# Show data in ajax table, jsp and servlets

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp

I have the following case that I am having a hard time solving.
In the image what I try to do is look for the documents of the selected process and that they are displayed in the table.

[image]

This is done with ajax, jsp and servlet.

For the **select** dropdown, this is the code where I list the processes through java and jsp classes.

```html
<select class="form-control js-example-basic-single" name="sucursal">
  <% 
    MantenedorProcesosLMD md = new MantenedorProcesosLMD();
    List<procesoslmd> ld = md.listar_proc_lista(con);
    for (procesoslmd p : ld) {
  %>
    <option value="<%=p.getLDM_ID()%>">
      <%=p.getLDM_NOMBPROCESOS()%>
    </option>
  <%
    }
  %>
</select>
```

This is my code in sql where by means of the **IDPROCESOS** parameter I look for the documents.

```sql
SELECT
  D.IDLDMDOCUMENTOS,
  LT.NOMBRETIPO,RTRIM(D.LDM_NOMENCLATURA) AS NOMENCLATURA,
  RTRIM(D.LDM_NOMBRE_DOCUMENTO) AS TITULO,
  D.LDM_FECHA_SUBIDA,D.LMD_RUTA_DOCUMENTO
FROM LDM_DOCUMENTOS_ D
LEFT JOIN LDM_PROCESOS_ LP ON LP.IDLDMPROCESOS = D.IDLDMPROCESOS
LEFT JOIN LDM_TIPO_DOCUMENTO_ LT ON LT.IDTIPODOC = D.IDTIPODOC
WHERE LP.IDLDMPROCESOS = @IDLDMPROCESOS
```

But so far I can't get to the code to find the documents by clicking the search button, I'm trying to do it with ajax I'm still collecting information.

implement this ajax code where I get the value of my select dropdown the **IDPROCESOS** and if it brings me the documents so far I can show it in the console, but I want to add it to the table but when I click on the search button

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('select[name=procesoldm]').on('change', function () {
        $.ajax({

            type: 'GET',
            url: '../sv_proxdocumento',
            data: 'codigoproceso='+$('select[name=procesoldm]').val(),
            statusCode: {
                404: function () {
                    alert('PAGINA NO ENCONTRADA');
                },
                500: function () {
                    alert('ERROR EN EL SERVIDOR');
                }

            },
            
            success: function (dados) {
           
                var pegadatos  = dados.split(":");
                console.log(pegadatos);
                 for (var i = 0; i < pegadatos.length -1; i++){
                     
                     var codigodocumento  = pegadatos[i].split("-")[0];
                     var nombretipo  = pegadatos[i].split("-")[1];
                     console.log(nombretipo);
                     
                     
                   
                     
                 }
            }

        });


    })
});
```

How do I pass that found data to a table with ajax, thanks for your time.

[image]

**how it should look in the table when clicking the search button**
[image]

Comment: Hi, how does your table look like with return data ? Can you show expected output  ? Also , please show output of `dados` .

Comment: that is what I want to achieve how to show these results obtained from dorpdown to a table some help please

Comment: Can you show expected output ? Which value should go in which column ?

Comment: I just edited and I have shown how it should look when selecting the dropdown process and clicking on the search button please your help thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use another for-loop after spliting your values and then on each iteration append `td` inside some variable using `+=` and then add this generated html inside your table.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  /*$('select[name=procesoldm]').on('change', function() {
    $.ajax({
    //other codes..
    success: function(dados) {*/
  //var pegadatos = dados.split(":");
  //just for demo
  var pegadatos = ["1-abc-abd-abdd-2/1/12", "2-abc2-abd2-abdd2-2/22/12", ""]
  var html = ""; //declare this
  //loop through main array
  for (var i = 0; i < pegadatos.length - 1; i++) {
    var values = pegadatos[i].split("-") //split values
    html += `<tr>`
    for (var j = 0; j < values.length; j++) {
      html += `<td>${values[j]}</td>` //splited values..
    }
    html += `<td>--Visitor--</td>`
    html += `</tr>`
  }
  $("table tbody").html(html) //add result inside tbody
  /*  }
    });
  })*/
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>No</th>
      <th>DocumentType</th>
      <th>DocumentNaming</th>
      <th>title</th>
      <th>date</th>
      <th>visitor</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```